# need help pivoting pandas table

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
print df
             output_time   position
0    2016-01-01 08:00:01      start
1    2016-01-01 08:07:53        end
2    2016-01-01 08:07:54      start
3    2016-01-01 08:09:23        end
4    2016-01-01 08:09:24      start
5    2016-01-01 08:32:51        end
```

I need the output as such (with df remaining a dataframe type not series type:

```
print df
              start                   end
2016-01-01 08:00:01   2016-01-01 08:07:53
2016-01-01 08:07:54   2016-01-01 08:09:23
2016-01-01 08:09:24   2016-01-01 08:32:51
```

`df = df.pivot_table(columns="output_time", values="position")` gives the following error:

> raise DataError('No numeric types to aggregate')
>       pandas.core.base.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

Answer (score 2):

Use [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) instead of `pivot_table`:

```
# Perform the pivot.
df = df.pivot(index=df.index//2, columns='position')

# Format the columns.
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0).rename(None)
```

The resulting output:

```
                  end               start
0 2016-01-01 08:07:53 2016-01-01 08:00:01
1 2016-01-01 08:09:23 2016-01-01 08:07:54
2 2016-01-01 08:32:51 2016-01-01 08:09:24
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for creating new `index` values with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df['g'] = df.groupby('position').cumcount()
df1 = df.set_index(['g','position']).unstack()
df1.columns = df1.columns.droplevel(0)
df1.columns.name = None
df1.index.name = None

print (df1)
                  end               start
0 2016-01-01 08:07:53 2016-01-01 08:00:01
1 2016-01-01 08:09:23 2016-01-01 08:07:54
2 2016-01-01 08:32:51 2016-01-01 08:09:24
```